# Is there a known API or module to automate Start/Stop activity for IBM WebSphere application servers with RPA?

Tags: server, automation, websphere, rpa, maintenance-plan

I need to automate the start/stop activity for some application servers in IBM WebSphere. Is there any api or module using which I can perform this using a RPA bot?

This is a part of a use case to set up a pipeline that will automate the monthly maintenance server patching activity for various applications servers.